# HTTP client -> [proxy] -> HTTPS server. Possible?

Tags: proxy, http, https

Is it possible to have something like this?:

[Client] ----HTTP--- > [Magic] ----HTTPS----> [Server]

I have a Windows Phone client that should connects to a HTTPS server which is out of my control. Trouble is, the test server is using a self signed cert, and Windows Phone doesn't allow connections to sites whose certificates are not signed by a trusted root certificate authority.

So is it possible to have some piece of software ([Magic]) act as a HTTP endpoint for the client, which would then, transparently to the client, forward the requests to the HTTPS server?

I've heard ISA server does this, but a lightweight solution would be preferable.

Comment: Why the downvote? Duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In nginx that is pretty simple.

```
upstream backend-secure {
  server 10.0.0.20:443;
}

server {
  listen 10.0.0.1:80;
  location / {
      proxy_pass https://backend-secure;
  }
}
```

You could also use HAProxy or Apache or anything similar.

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm! Even though I'm new to nginx and I don't understand everything, I can get on with work!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, anything capable of acting as a reverse proxy should be able to do this -- Apache, nginx, varnish.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! So the keyword I should be searching for is 'reverse proxy'. Sorry, I'm still just a dev aspiring to be a network guy.